# Can I wear two hat simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Can I wear two hat simultaneously like this?

[image]

Comment: I am asking about two different hat not same hat.

Comment: wear johny three hats :P

Comment: +1 that's something I offered myself for next year. :)

Answer (score 8):

Only if your name is Zaphod Beeblebrox.

And yes, that name is already in use.

Comment: Who the hell is Zaphod Beeblebrox?

Comment: [Zaphod Beeblebrox](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Mark_Wing-Davey_as_Zaphod_Beeblebrox.jpg)

Comment: Cool. :) +1 Thanks @Vigbyor

Answer (score 6):

This feature is not present at present but you can do it in alternate way,

- Edit your profile snap-shot with a hat and upload it in your profile.
- Wear another hat that you have earned.
- Done.

Comment: like OP added pic in post.