# Unable to delete downvoted post

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Recently I asked this question on meta:

[Can I wear two hat simultaneously?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213909/can-i-wear-two-hat-simultaneously)

This question was marked as a duplicate. That's fine. Now some people downvote my question and I wanna delete mention post but unable to do so. So here my question is if any question is marked as a duplicate then why people answer those posts, why other people downvote same post (Mostly on Meta only!) and why the person who posted is unable to delete same post?

Comment: You can't delete it because it has upvoted answers.

Comment: @JoshC But my question was downvoted. What should I do with answer? I dont want any of downvoted post in my pofile.

Comment: Never mind. Everyone with a significant activity on Meta has downvoted posts. Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of the site, has some of the most downvoted contributions in the place's history

Comment: @Pëkka So here downVote is Upvote and Upvote is down right!

Comment: I didn't say that. I said everyone here has some downvotes under their belt because it's a place with more subjectivity that Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's just how Meta works. There are no rules for voting.

Answer (score 5):

No one will like downvoted questions. But it's rule of site, that

> You simply cannot delete a question with answer posted on it. (Upvote doesn't matter.)

I had a same problem with one question of mine. I kept receiving downvote after months due to that question. I tried to delete it. But it showed,

[image]

And flag won't be accepted till it's valid.

So there's just one thing you can do: In future, ask better questions.

Because answers are not going to be deleted by other user as your question was not good.